# SortableTableView: how to get clicked view from table?

Tags: android

I use library "SortableTableView". I create a table and add ImageButtons there.
When the user clicks on a button, I have to change the button image.
So how can I take the clicked button from activity?

Here is my adapter:

```
class CallRecordsTableDataAdapter extends TableDataAdapter {
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    private final int TEXT_SIZE = 14;
    private DataManager mDataManager;
    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int index);
    }

    public CallRecordsTableDataAdapter(Context context, List<Datum> data, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        super(context, data);
        mDataManager = AppDataManager.getInstance();
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public View getCellView(int rowIndex, int columnIndex, ViewGroup parentView) {
        final Datum datum = (Datum) getRowData(rowIndex);
        View renderedView = null;
        switch (columnIndex) {

            //Play
        case 1:
            renderedView = renderImage(rowIndex);
            break;
        }
        return renderedView;
    }

    private ImageButton renderImage(int rowIndex) {
        //TODO mogut bit problemi
        final ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(getContext());
        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(v -> listener.onItemClick(rowIndex));
        return imageButton;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need help with making an ImageButton respond to being clicked?

Comment: @LAD yes. when user press button id like to show vector animate inside imagebutton. i can detect click and get clicked row. but how can exactly get image button in a selected row, in second column?